# How I get with GetEnumerator in Fsharp a seq out of a seq?

Tags: f#, seq

For my project I want to pull out the seq of seq>. For this I thought I can use GetEnumerator. After that I want to compare the head (with Seq.head of the current element), if it contains an Element of my choice. The Problem is, that if I use .Current it gives me back obj instead of seq. I have done something wrong?

```
let convertElements (input:seq<seq<Elements>>) =
    let en = input.GetEnumerator()
    let rec loop (en:System.Collections.IEnumerator) =
        match en.MoveNext() with
            | true  -> match (Seq.head en.Current) with
                        |AElement(_) -> createNewA andSoOn
                        |_    -> ()
            | false -> ()    
    loop en
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<'T>`, rather than `System.Collections.IEnumerator`. The latter is basically a remnant from the dark times of C# 1.0 when generics didn't exist in .NET, so it doesn't know the type of your elements.

Comment: Ah! That was it! Thank you! I use F# for a month and still have some problems.

Comment: Sry if the question was too banal.